# get sublist of all elements that create specific word prolog

Tags: prolog

i want to get a sublist of all elements that assemble specific word for example
for the call

```
assemble([hello,'',world,hi,bye,good,well], 'hello world', A).
```

program should print

```
A=[hello,'',world]
```

for the call

```
assemble([abc,123,ab,c,123],'abc123', A).
```

program should print

```
A=[abc,123];
A=[ab,c,123];
```

thanks for your help.

```
matchwords(W1, W2, Results) :-
    setof(R, matchw(W1, W2, R), RSet), % Collect all the matching substrings
                                       % and their lengths
    reverse(RSet, Set),                % Order by longest first
    highest(Set, Results).             % keep only the highest ones

matchw(W1, W2, N-Result) :-
    atom_chars(W1, A1),
    atom_chars(W2, A2),
    matchl(A1, A2, R),
    length(R, N),
    atom_chars(Result, R).

matchl([H|T1], [H|T2], [H|T]) :-
    matchl(T1, T2, T).
matchl([H1|T1], [H2|T2], R) :-
    H1 \= H2,
    ( matchl(T1, [H2|T2], R) ; matchl([H1|T1], T2, R) ).
matchl([], _, []).
matchl([_|_], [], []).

highest([_-W], [W]).
highest([N1-W1,N2-_|_], [W1]) :-
    N1 > N2.
highest([N1-W1,N2-W2|T], [W1|WT]) :-
    N1 = N2,
    highest([N2-W2|T], WT).
```

Comment: Please share your efforts !

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's your specific Prolog programming question regarding where you are stuck? You might want to visit the Prolog documentation and read about the atom and string processing predicates.

Comment: What about `assemble([a,b],ba,A)`?

Comment: add my code above